# No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

Okay, so I've been trying to set up the CPU version of tensorflow on my 64 bit machine, but I've come across a common problem that even the docs point out.
It suggested that I install [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685), which I have:

[image: Control Panel]

but I still get the "No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'" error when I run `import tensorflow` in python commmand line.

However I couldn't find the `MSVCP140.DLL` in the Path variable (not sure if I'm looking at the right place)

[image: Path variable]

How do I fix this? Why is it so complicated to install a single python library...
Anyway, in order to get the 2015 Redistributable working, I had to uninstall the 2017 version. (maybe that has to do something with it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after many hours of looking for an answer, **I finally got it**.
These are the steps you need to follow:

1. Downgrade to Python 3.5 (3.6 and above are not supported for Tensorflow).
2. Uninstall Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (both x86 and x64) if you already have it (usually comes with Win 10, but is not supported I suppose)
3. Install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685])
4. Run `python -m pip install --upgrade  https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` in command line.
   note: Upgrade pip to version 9 if this step gives you an error about some wheel.

voilà